# What can you say about two independent events A and B in a Sample space S

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

If we assume that A and B are disjoint example P(A∩B) = 0, what can I say about P(A) and P(B)

Comment: Disjoint events are not independent (i guess im confused by title and what you said about disjointness)

Comment: I am very confused about the question as well, cuz it said that that Consider two independent events A and B in a sample space S. If We assume that A and B are disjoint,.., Pr(A∩B) = 0. What can you say about Pr(A) and Pr(B)? justify the answer

Comment: Oh then its saying that you know that at least one must have probability $0$. Since $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ by independence and $P(A\cap B)=P(\emptyset)=0$ by disjointness

Answer (score 2):

If they are independent then $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$. If they are disjoint, this is $0$, so $\Pr(A)=0$ or $\Pr(B)=0$.

Comment: I'm guessing the word "independent" is a red herring added to the problem incorrectly by the user. This assignment seems like it's looking for the inclusion-exclusion formula.

Comment: Maybe we will find out. I have assigned questions of this genre, since some students think independent and disjoint mean the same thing.